# Spring integration - transform soap response

Tags: jms, spring-integration

We have Payload as below, and would like to extract the value

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns2:DCResponse xmlns:ns2="http://bgs.beienst.kl/tm/">
    <ns2:sdate>2016-01-04</ns2:sdate></ns2:DCResponse>
```

The spring integration config has tyhe below transformer,

```
<int-xml:xpath-transformer input-channel="tcSoapChannel" output-channel= "tcOutputChannel"  evaluation-type="NODE_RESULT" 
      xpath-expression="//DCResponse/sdate" />
```

Do I need to specify namespace and if so how?

I want to get value - 2016-01-04, but getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `xpath-expression-ref` isntead:

```
            <xsd:attribute name="xpath-expression-ref" type="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
Reference to the XPathExpression instance to be evaluated against the input Message's payload.
Either this or 'xpath-expression' must be provided, but not both.
                        </xsd:documentation>
                        <xsd:appinfo>
                            <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                                <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpression"/>
                            </tool:annotation>
                        </xsd:appinfo>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:attribute>
```

So, you can configure a bean like:

```
<int-xml:xpath-expression id="xpathExpression" expression="//DCResponse/sdate" 
                          ns-prefix="ns2" ns-uri="http://bgs.beienst.kl/tm/"/>
```

Comment: Defined bean as above and used in transformer.<int-xml:xpath-transformer input-channel="thannel" output-channel="dest-channel"  
         xpath-expression-ref="xpathExpression" />. Thank you Artem